# Custom direct graph with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I found this code on git, it permit to create a graph like the attached picture.
I want to update the code to be able to choose other custom node (triangle, rectangle,...) in addition to the circle:

https://gist.github.com/cjrd/6863459

I want also to be able to choose the label of the node from a dropdown list saved on sql server database.

Is that possible ?

[image]

Comment: You can use `rect` and `polygon` elements instead of `circle`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I want also to add a Dropbox from an sql server database to choose the label. Do you have examples?